# How to map compile and execute in vim?

Tags: compilation, vi

I want to have a command to compile and execute the C file that I'm editing in vim. How can I do it? The following doesn't work because of the .c in the filename.

```
:map <leader>m :!make && ./%
```

If I use `:!make && ./filename` I don't know how to move through the output so I'd like to see a solution with a vertical split window too.

Answer (score 0):

Your shell escape  in `:map <leader>m :!make && ./%` calls the make program, which searches for a Makefile to process. The recipes in the Makefile describe how your program is compiled, and how the final executable is named (or it defaults to `a.out` if omitted).
While the name of the file you are editing (referenced by `%`) might have the same prefix as your desired executable filename, this is not guaranteed.

To compile, run, and edit the output of your program in a split window write a Makefile recipe that is automatically run after compilation and redirects the output of your executable in a temporary file, e.g.:

```
.PHONY: all

all: executablename runlog

executablename: executablename.c
        cc -o executablename executablename.c

runlog: executablename
        ./executablename >runlog
```

Keep in mind that the 8 indention spaces need to be replaced with a tab for the Makefile to function.

Reference the temporary file in your mapping:
`:map <leader>m :!make^M:sp runlog^M` where `^M` stems from typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Return</kbd>.

Comment: The time saved with the leader shortcut is gonna be spent deleting the extra files.

Comment: You do not have to delete any file for this, because the shell redirection _>runlog_ inside the Makefile overwrites _runlog_ every time. If you worry about the file, redirect to _/tmp/runlog_cleaned_up_by_system_ or add the removal to a clean recipe in your Makefile. Besides I do not understand your intention on saving time with a leader mapping (compared to a regular mapping), to my understanding leader is just a convenient name space for your own mappings.

Comment: How would I do it if I had to different programs to compile in the same Makefile? There isn't a way to use the name of the file minus the .filetype?

Comment: Using the name of the file minus the filetype extension is not possible in _vi_, but if you run _vim_, which is likely, you could try _expand('%:r')_. Typing _:echo expand('%:r')_ demonstrates the modification applied by _:r_.